# Remap the `Caps Lock` key as `Ctrl` in X11

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I wanted to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> to <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys. And I found this [post](https://rogerkeays.com/vim-key-bindings-in-ubuntu-using-xmodmap) and did something like this:

```
! add Mode_switch
keycode 66 = NoSymbol NoSymbol
keycode 66 = Mode_switch

keycode 57 = n N Down
keycode 33 = p P Up
```

And it kinda works. But there's one problem - I actually wanted <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and also do that. I can't seem to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Your remappings of Ctrl+N and Ctrl+P in your last two lines are fine.
The problem lies in the attempt to remap the Caps_Lock button (keycode 66 decimal, or 0x42 hex).

Caps Lock is one of the **modifier** keys, along with Shift and Control (Ctrl). X.org maintains a table of modifier mappings as well as the familiar key mappings. `xmodmap -pm` will show you your current modifier map. You'll need to update that map as well as the keymap, as I explain below:

The (Caps) Lock modifier, that gives the characteristic behaviour of locking capitals on, won't release the physical key for other purposes unless you explicitly tell it to. Personally, I always used to pry off my Caps Lock key with a screwdriver, it annoyed me so much, so I'm happy to clear it entirely, with `clear Lock`.

*(I've also seen people enable changes to their Lock bindings by surrounding them with
`remove MODIFIERNAME = KEYSYMNAME ...` and
`add MODIFIER = KEYSYMNAME`. Check out `man xmodmap` for details.)*

```
clear Lock
keycode 66 = Control_L
add Control = Control_L
```

After the Lock modifier has been told to release the Caps_Lock key, you're free to remap that key (`keycode 66` in line 2 of the snippet) to one of the Ctrl keys - in this case I've chosen the left one, hence the `_L`, but it doesn't really matter which. Now the Caps_Lock key "thinks" it's a Ctrl key, but the modifiers table doesn't yet know that we want to use it as a modifier.

The last line in my listing declares that Control_L is a new Control modifier, and should therefore *act* like a Ctrl key. Look at the before/after comparison of the modifier maps (from `xmodmap -pm`) below:

[image: Before: the Caps_Lock key belongs to the Lock modifier.]
**Before:** the Caps_Lock key belongs to the Lock modifier.

[image: After: the keycode identifying the physical Caps_Lock key (66/0x42) now identifies as an additional left Control key, still with Caps_Lock's original keycode, and has now moved from the Lock modifier to the Control modifier in the modifier map. The original left Control key is still there, too.]
**After:** the keycode identifying the physical Caps_Lock key (66/0x42) now identifies as an additional left Control key, still with Caps_Lock's original keycode, and has now moved from the Lock modifier to the Control modifier in the modifier map. The original left Control key is still there, too.